# React parent is unmounted for child?

Tags: reactjs, components, parent, mount, unmount

I have a `React` `Parent` and `Child` component. The Child has to be able to update the state of the Parent component. However, I have the issue that my `Parent is unmounted` when the `Child wants to update the Parent`, and I'm not sure why or how to fix that?

I'm pasting the simplified code that is relevant to the issue. In this case, the child wants to update the `page Title` that is rendered in the `Parent`. But sadly, in the `componentDidMount()` of the Child (where this update happens) the Parent is already `unmounted`.

The `index.js` loads the `Child` directly but it wraps the `Parent` component around it. I guess that has something to do with the `Parent` component unmounting?

**Parent:**

```
type Props = TranslationProps & {
  Component: any
};
type State = {
  setTitle: string
};

export class Layout extends Component<Props, State> {
  _isMounted = false;

  constructor(props:Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      setTitle: ""
    };
  }

 componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, ...restProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <Component
        setTitle={title=> this._isMounted && this.setState({ setTitle: title})}
        isMounted={this._isMounted}
        {...restProps}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**Child:**

```
type Props = TranslationProps & {
  setTitle: (data: string) => void,
  isMounted: boolean
};

componentDidMount() {
    const { t } = this.props;
    if(this.props.isMounted) {
      this.props.setTitle("Test title");
    }
  }
```

**Index:**

```
const unwrap = component => {
  if(component.WrappedComponent) {
    return unwrap(component.WrappedComponent);
  }

  return component;
}

let reactMounts = document.querySelectorAll("[data-react]");
for (let reactMount of reactMounts) {
  let Component = Components[reactMount.dataset.react];
  let UnwrappedComponent = unwrap(Component);
  console.log("Rendering", Component, " (", UnwrappedComponent, ") to ", reactMount);

  let data = {
    ...reactMount.dataset,
    Component
  };
  delete data.react;

  render(
    React.createElement(Components['Layout'], data),
    reactMount
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Reason: Accoring to React life-cycle, Child Component rendered before ComponentDidMount (where _isMounted = true). So, I guess the this._isMounted variable in setTitle props always = false => bug.
- Solution: I recommend that you should create callback function in class, after that passing in setTitle props.

Comment: Hi - what do you mean with creating the callback function in class? Where would that be?